# What makes a good alternative to flipping a coin for 50/50 randomness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, components, luck, random

I'm building a coin-flip themed Commander deck, and I realise I'm going to be flipping potentially dozens of coins every turn deeper into a match.

What would be a good alternative to flipping an actual, physical coin that fits the following criteria?

1. Can be done many times quickly.
2. Serial, not parallel (not doing many at once, but many in order).
3. Requires minimal maths/mental effort.
4. Isn't "messy"; flipping a coin risks losing it across the room or under a table. I'd like to avoid similar issues.
5. Is a truly random 50/50 proposition.

Bonus points for fun and aesthetically pleasing answers.

Comment: Is "parallel" okay if there is a way of telling the order of heads/tails? For example, a d8 and a lookup table can give you 3 ordered 50/50 results.

Comment: I think while that's an interesting idea it violates the "minimum mental effort" part. It should be readily understood not just by me but by everyone at the table. Cool idea though!

Comment: I'm not really sure that you can get anything simpler than "oh, rolled a 5, handy laminated card says thats HTT". Although you can get d16s :)

Comment: Flipping a coin is of course not truly 50/50 random but can be made [perfectly fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin). That would definitely be overkill.

Comment: Reading the entrails of a chicken?

Comment: What's controlling this, please? Is it some kind of hardware spring, or some software or what?

Comment: Use [this algorithm](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Most of the answers seem to be focussed on 50/50 randomness, and OP doesn't yet like any of them. Is true 50/50 randomness more important than the other requirements?

Comment: "True" 50/50 is of course a slightly philosophical question, but yeah, I want to use this in games with people, so it has to be fair of course :)

Answer (score 24):

**Use a coinflip app, or physical 4- or 6-sided dice (calling odd/even or above/below half instead of heads/tails).**

Both solutions fulfill all your criteria. You can further secure dice against falling off with a dice bowl or cup. Dice have the additional advantage of parallel flips, should the need arise despite your stipulation.

Comment: Yep, just roll a bunch of dice, calling evens as "heads" and odds as "tails" (or vice-versa). They don't even all have to be the same kind, as long as they are have an even number of sides (all standard 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, or 20-sided dice would work).

Comment: You can have simultanously rolled sequential results with a couple of dice of different colors. E.g. take a red, green and a blue die, and roll all at once, reading the results in this order (RGB should be easy to remember). You can't use that for cases where you make decisions between the rolls, but if you know you're going to, say, roll until you get tails and just need to count, then a result of H-T-H would count as rolling one heads, one tails and stopping there (with the last die ignored). Not to say that would be accepted in all settings, but it should work in principle.

Comment: The dice method is what really got my upvote here, as I would call the dice-rolling app both non-random (seeing as best case, it uses a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), and worst case, it isn't even designed to be random, or the developer made an error leading to it not being random), and messy (you have to start the app, leave the phone somewhere, keep the screen on or unlock the device again, and maybe players won't all be able to see what's on the screen at the same time - it's a not very elegant solution to an easy-to-solve-nondigitally issue)

Comment: @TheThirdMan A PRNG is significantly more random than physically rolling dice, especially if they aren't casino quality. And either is far more random than actually needed for the purpose.

Comment: @TheThirdMan modern PRNGs are practically indistinguishable from true RNGs. They are good enough for cryptography and regulated online gambling, so they're good enough for mtg coin flipping.

Comment: @Hackworth: the PRNGs likely to be used in an app are very unlikely to be the same RNGs used for cryptography, and gambling sites will be doing things the app won't. That said, a properly developed app should be more than good enough although I wouldn't trust a random app from the app store to be handling its random numbers properly. Bad PRNGs and/or badly used PRNGs are very common in the programming world

Comment: Of course you can, in theory. When more than 50 years ago my maths class tried to prove that, by having 30-odd kids flip 50 dice each, it was very obvious that faces 2 and 5 came up more than any other

Comment: @TheThirdMan modern phone processors actually have proper actual sources of randomness built into the hardware, and even if they didn't, the operating system can synthesize seemingly random bits from external events (read latencies, sensors, RF data,…) to produce *excellent* randomness. So, unless a dice roll app does something stupid (like not using the operating system-supplied random device to seed a PRNG, or to draw a number for the dice every time, because, well, human dice-requesting speed is quite slow and there's enough entropy in that system), consider a phone dice app a true RNG.

Comment: I'm not saying PRNG are inadequate by design, I'm saying there's always the possibility they're improperly or not at all used by any app. I'm very much with Jack Aidley in this regard, and therefore will not trust randomness until proven otherwise, but the other way round. Whether it makes a practical difference to the task at hand is a different story, I'll leave that to the reader - but not mentioning this, or claiming apps are trustworthy by default, is in my mind not fulfilling the "random 50/50 proposition" requirement in the question, even when interpreting the word "truly" loosely.

Comment: @JackAidley Even the most basic PRNG built into any language down to Basic are significantly superior to physical dice in randomness. Using them is easy, randomize(); x=random(); is all it takes. They might not have enough entropy to withstand a cryptanalysis attack, but more than enough for a game.

Comment: @Therac If you think you can do that and get decent results in every language, then you are very much mistaken. Also the way you turn random () into a coin-flip or dice roll matters. Yet alone shuffling a deck of cards.

Comment: @TheThirdMan It's a card game, not a nuclear reactor. It could be the worst PRNG you've ever heard of and it would still be good enough.

Comment: Either there's no interest in discourse here, or I haven't made myself clear that some PRNGs (perhaps most) might be alright. Somehow still, between poorly made /intentionally rigged dice apps, or the question asking for "truly 50/50", apparently still literally every kind of app is trustworthy enough. Of course die rolls don't produce perfectly random rolls either, but assuming from the question that a sensibly similar method to coin tossing would be acceptable seems logical. What makes coins/dice work for games is eliminating the possibility of predictability, which an app cannot (easily) do

Comment: @JackAidley **Every mainstream language.** Obviously you won't get a good result in Brainfuck. No one's writing coin-flipping apps in Brainfuck. It is that easy. I'm a developer. All mainstream languages' PRNG are good enough for a card game. They might not stand up to a hacker attack involving planted spyware or distributed decryption, but are far above the ability of an unaided human to fool or predict.

Comment: @Therac You're wrong. Go and study. There is no more to say about it.

Comment: @JackAidley I have advised theses on random number generation. You're being a bit grandiose towards Therac there; defaults actually are more than good enough: C++ (std::random, Mersenne Twister on 2¹⁹⁹³⁷-1), Java (java.util.random: L32X64MixRandom), JavaScript (Xoroshiro128+, which is so good while compact that we implemented it in hardware during one thesis), Python (Cpython:same MT19937 as C++), Swift (pre-4.2, people used arc4random, after which things got even better), rust (rand::rng, ChaCha 20 or 12).... Could you explain to me which language you're specifically referring to?

Comment: FWIW, the C language makes no guarantees whatsoever about the quality of the rand() function in the standard library and and some stdc libraries had really bad implementations.

Comment: @nwellnhof Define "bad implementation". Bad as in something tangential as "slow performance", or bad as in "noticably non-uniform distribution over tiny sample sizes"? Just to keep this discussion on topic a little.

Comment: @Hackworth Bad in this case usually means significant bias, but small samples are largely pointless for checking a PRNG, because even a _perfect_ PRNG will return runs of the same number from time to time, and even truly terrible PRNGs (say, IBM’s RANDU for example, which actually passes a handful of the standard diehard tests and doesn’t ‘look’ biased to most people) can show little to no visible bias or nonuniformity even with very large sample sizes if you don’t do the right type of testing.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a phone which has a sufficiently accurate stopwatch (probably hundredths of a second is good enough, thousandths would be better) such that you can't reliably stop the stopwatch on any single digit, you could just start and stop the stopwatch repeatedly and use the parity of the final digit (i.e. odd/even where odd=heads, even=tails).

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. It's a valid method and probably less easy to bias than a coin flip: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2789164/

Comment: I mean, if you have a phone, you have a device with a true random number generator built in.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I don't quite follow your argument in your first comment. The advantage of this method is that it only requires a 'vanilla' phone - i.e. there is no need to install any additional software.

Comment: Ah! I see your point; thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Some theorists would object to the notion that any phone has a "true" random number generator in it. I’m no expert on randomness, although I’m not totally naive either, and I’m not able to follow your reasoning of why you think the stopwatch method is "less random" than another method. It seems like you’re saying it *might* be less random and since we’re not **sure** that it’s random means it’s not as good an answer? If so, I’d counter that the uncertainty about its randomness is part of its randomness and that seems like more than enough randomness for a game. It’s not crypto.

Comment: @NeilTarrant I looked up the source code of the current AOSP/Android UI stopwatch. I'm not too versed in Android UI programming and the APIs, but assuming users will not install a *worse* stopwatch app, it seems to be quite safe to assume that last digits will be quite random. I removed my comments to that end, because while I think the concern is valid, I have been overstating it. My apologies.

Comment: @ToddWilcox due to a cleanup, my comment there got lost: I don't think theorists have significant problems with saying that a quantum-phenomena observing component in a modern CPU is truly random! There might be implementation issues, but in theory, things should be quite truly random. (the implementation deficiencies: at least intel's implementation for x86, `RDRAND`, got FIPS approval, so it does seem to be on all things that you can test and that you can read from a description of the device, the randomness is true.)

Answer (score 9):

## Prologue: Why Randomness Is (Not) Hard in Real Life

Disclaimer: I might have designed too many *probability theory basics* exam questions in my life; whether this left permanent damage is up to you to judge.

---

What I really like is finding mechanical apparatus that behave randomly: That's slightly surprisingly a bit of a challenge: Our reality is full of true randomness, and unless you restrict yourself to (often rather artificially-feeling) experiments where that is really *not* the case (like drawing colored marbles from an urn without putting them back, or cards from a deck), you can model extremely many phenomena as truly 50/50.

Small problem is that these really random effects tend to happen on a microscopic or very weak level – you need some amplification to see them! That's why the computer (or phone) based answers are *excellent*: These devices both include true random number sources<sup>1,2</sup>: because they're anyways based on electronic logic dealing with very small phenomena, it's inherently possible to measure these small random effects and translate them into values observable by software. (People like to say that "randomness on a deterministic machine like a computer is hard", but that's not really the case. Millions are spent keeping the random behaviour *out* of a computer processor, each time one is designed, because the effects that make your computer work are really only a bit stronger than what noise you can expect. And that noise is random.)

## Building a Good Tosser

<sup>Good: Truly fair, truly uncorrelated, and most of all: fast and easy to use</sup>

Now, I think computers are cool; I really think that a neat little box with a small half-spherical dome on top where a small "coin" disk is spun on a horizontal axis by  a motor, controlled by a 1€ microcontroller that takes a bit of truly random external input to compute nearly arbitrarily many random throws would be the nicest solution in terms of usability. Put a little momentary switch on the bottom of the box to trigger the "toss" with a satisfying **smack** on the top.
It will be quite hard to beat that in terms of fairness and uncorrelatedness, in addition of the ease-of-use³.

## Building a  Beautiful Randomification Device

But the hardcore usability and probability side ignored, what *mechanical* ways are there to amplify a small random effect in a way that stays really random.

Two devices that already exist come to mind:

### Magnetic Pendulum

Just like the actual coin toss, this isn't actually *random*: toss a coin twice *in exactly the same way*, it will land the same way. There's a deterministic input/output relationship. The thing is that humans just aren't great tossers, so that basically never happens in amateurs (whether someone could train to throw a coin reliably, I guess they could! Have you seen olympic archers?).

The main thing why "throwing a coin" seems fair is that the movement it makes for the methods we usually use when throwing seems *chaotic*, i.e., tiny changes in input conditions lead to very drastic changes in output.

Here's a picture of *one* possible implementation of a magnetic pendulum:

[image: Magnetic Pendulum with 3 magnets]
<sup>Source: Chalk Dust Magazine, Authors *James Christian* and *Holly Middleton-Spencer*, [Link](http://chalkdustmagazine.com/features/the-magnetic-pendulum/)</sup>

You can build one with an even number of magnets, as well. It's very hard to predict from the initial position at which magnet the pendulum will end up; I found the simulation on [this](https://beltoforion.de/en/magnetic_pendulum/) website very beautiful.

### Galton Board

Now, this is *Fancy* (capital F) and overkill, because in the form that you usually see it it's used to demonstrate what happens when you chain *a lot* of identical, but independent, random decisions:

[image: Galton Box]
<sup>[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Galton_box.jpg) User Matemateca (IME USP); CC-BY SA 4.0</sup>

The loads of balls are dropped through the narrow channel on top, each of them hits various pegs on the way down, and each time takes a random left or right. See the device in action [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Galton_box.webm).

Of course, instead of throwing hundreds of balls at once, you could throw *one* down the chute (that ends up being a game quite similar to *Pachinko*), and base your head/tails decision on whether it comes out left or right.

Because you don't care to see the beautiful Gaussian distribution, just the half it comes out in, you could omit the outer pegs on the lower rows, where a deflection can no longer change the side the ball comes out.

Technically, of course, you would need but a single peg and a very precise chute for your ball, but keeping tolerances and sizes in check, at least a few pegs which stand a fair chance of cancelling bias is probably a good idea; also, more clang = more fun.

---

¹ on x86 (i.e.,  your laptop/desktop): [`RDRAND`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND)

² on ARM application processors (i.e., in your phone, your TV or your smart camera), you typically find peripherals that offer true physical random numbers at some address in memory space

³ I might be crazy enough that if someone funded me for that product development, I might be willing to undertake that engineering effort.

Comment: Galton Board? PACHINKO!

Answer (score 5):

Using either Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets, the formula =RANDBETWEEN(0,1) will give you 50/50 odds of a 0 or 1.  On a PC, hit the delete key on an empty cell to re-roll (or F9 works in Excel too). I'm sure there's a Mac equivalent. Copy the cell to as many cells as you want if you want to see several re-rolls in order.

p.s., as others have stated with other answers, this answer is also PRNG, but it's practical and more than sufficient for your use case.

Comment: You are right that pseudorandom generator is much better than a coin flip and probably takes less effort to defeat (depending on how terrible your PRNG is): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2789164/

Answer (score 4):

A wonderfully horrible solution for RNG is an old-fashioned dice popper. They make for a literal pushbutton solution to RNG, with no dice falling off tables. They also make a sound that is either mildly annoying or just the right amount of kitsch, depending on your personality.

[image: Vintage Dice Popper]

Answer (score 2):

A very simple low-tech solution:

**Use one or more decks of cards**

- Shuffle the cards and lay face down.
- Turn the top card for a random 50/50 decision: red or black.
- Place in a discarded pile.
- Shuffle and restart when they run out.

---

Two suggestions to make the last card unpredicatable:

- Keep the Jokers in the pack and reshuffle when one is turned.
- Cut the pack after each shuffle and put one part out of play.

Comment: Probably better to re-shuffle before it runs out. The closer you get to the end, the more predictable it gets, to the point that the last one is always 100% predictable (if somebody's willing to keep count of what's come up previously).

Comment: @JerryCoffin yes, you would only need to track the parity to know the last card. I've added a solution.

Comment: This is going to frequently violate OP's 5th condition. Whenever there's an odd number of cards remaining, you no longer have 50/50. And even when there's an even number remaining, you still might not have 50/50 depending on the previous draws

Comment: @anjama your proposal is false, because the previous draws may not have had an exact number of each. It's a random shuffle, so there may have been twice as many reds as blacks drawn up till that point. Anyway the deck is randomly split (the cut), or randomly shuffled (the Joker).

Comment: @WeatherVane Your solutions don't fix the issue. Anytime you draw and reveal a card, you have new information to calculate new probabilities. Splitting the deck or shuffling early is irrelevant to this; all they do is limit how far you get before you start over. In other words, they stop you from reaching a point of 100% certainty most of the time. Here's actually a topic that illustrates this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569562/what-is-the-probability-of-picking-a-card-from-a-deck-of-cards-that-was-split-in You can update the equations there for colors instead of a specific card

Comment: @WeatherVane And as an extreme example, let's say you shuffle and split the deck, and your pile just so happens to have 25 red cards on top of one or more black cards. After 25 draws, you've seen every red card, and now every draw after that until the shuffle you have 100% probability of black. A true solution should not have failures like this

Comment: @anjama it's a *game*, not betting. Although it's not strictly 50/50, the other requirements are met: quick, serial, effortless and tidy. To improve the 50/50, after each draw cut the pack and replace the card in between. Shuffle when a joker is turned. Of course, you could replace and shuffle the pack after every draw, but then it would not be so quick.

Comment: @WeatherVane the question was what a *good* alternative is. This is about as bad as it gets – highly correlated results.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a quick and easy solution that fully meets 4 out of 5 of the OP's requirements, and for a game isn't far off the fifth. There was no requirement to ban cheating. Which of those four is "as bad as it gets"? Do you really want to sit there consulting a perfect randomness on a laptop? Which is actually quite hard too.

Comment: 4 out of 5 requirements fulfilled, or as we engineers would say: requirements not fulfilled. Also, if "many" times is > 52, then your method also fails requirement 1.

Comment: Yeah right, it takes one second to shuffle a pack. The question is about much more than obtaining true 50/50 randomness anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm not of a regular card player to do that. I doubt anyone is; I've know croupiers, and they would take longer, because otherwise you just risk long streaks of exactly the same sequence as last time.

Comment: @Marcus, this is a *parlour game* FFS. Please post your answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane um, I'm allowed to comment on your answer without posting one of my own; please don't act as if it's not allowed to remark when something fails to meet requirements.

Comment: @Marcus, this method requires *no preparation* but you've been banging on about how this can be done on a phone. Please post your answer that satisfies all the contitions.

Comment: @WeatherVane "no preparation" is not a requirement. "Truly 50/50" is.

Comment: 3. Requires minimal maths/mental effort. 5. was the last/least requirement.

Comment: There's no "least requirements": there's *requirements*, properties that are required of a solution. And "minimal maths/mental effort" is very distinctiively not the same as "no preparation".

Comment: OK, so how long does it take Joe Bloggs to set up a truly random 50/50 generator on their phone? Write an app? Install one from the app store? I get out a deck of cards. I'm out of here, just downvote *please* if you think this is such a bad answer as you make out.

Comment: I will have to search for a deck of cards, but on my phone, I need about 10s to install a dice app (I just tried). Anyways, complaining about a solution that I like is not excusing your bad not-solution.

Comment: I don't have a phone, and nor does my Grandma.

Comment: I don't understand how badmouthing the phone proposition changes the fact that your proposed method doesn't fulfill what you throw a coin for, namely, for a 50/50 chance? Is your whole argument "yeah but you mentioned a phone app and I think that's dumb?", because in that case I think you might be trying to apply a whataboutism, and badly so.

Comment: I am not badmouthing anything, and never mentioned 'dumb'. If you have a better solution: **post it** instead of banging on everywhere about how good that would be. Like "use a dice app." But this is *my* solution even if you don't approve.

Comment: @WeatherVane you're deflecting. Your answer is bad. I can observe and state that without having my own answer.

Comment: After the first draw, the distribution of the deck is 26:25, and no amount of cutting or reshuffling will change that, the second card (already) isn't 50-50. You'd have to shuffle the drawn card pack, or search through the deck for another of the opposite color also remove (and then shuffle anyway) to balance it. Or, if you don't want to do that, you should at least admit that it's biased. Even with a perfect shuffle (which could be taken as similar to a perfectly symmetrical shape, which is something we implicitly assume of dice anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Use a spinner, like the one that comes with the popular "Game of Life" board game, except each of the numbers alternates with "heads" or "tails" (or whatever 2 categories you prefer). From personal experience, this is faster and less messy than flipping coins or rolling dice. And it's fun!

[image]

Comment: Those spinners (especially the ones in *Life* game boards) were terrible.  When I was a kid, ours had the wheel bearing far enough off center that about 1/3 of the wheel didn't even click on the tab, so the wheel couldn't stop at those numbers.  If you want to use something that spins, find a well made dreidel.

Comment: @ZeissIkon It's totally feasible to make a not-bad spinner though. A dreidel is not a bad idea, but IMO the downsides are similar to dice--except it trades messiness for time it takes to get a result.

Answer (score 0):

**Start an AC motor**

When started, AC motors will rotate in a random direction (unless they're specifically designed to run in one direction).

Possibly the most obvious example of this is microwave turntables. Start a microwave (put a cup of water in it first), and if it's turning clockwise it's heads; anticlockwise tails.

If you can get your hands on such a motor without the surrounding microwave, you can probably come up with all sorts of fun embellishments for it.

Comment: I have no idea how needing a motor with an AC source is somehow better than a coin flip.

Comment: @Nelson Well, it meets all the criteria in the OP. Portability isn't one of them.

Comment: You mean it completely doesn't fit 1 and 4? 1) Can be done many times quickly. 4) Isn't "messy"...

Comment: My microwave reliably starts the turntable opposite the way it ran last (unless it's been unplugged or power was off); I think the internal controller is programmed for this.  Most if not all of those use a stepper motor for that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: use cryptographically secure `os.urandom` for true randomness

#### Python one-liner

You could install [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and run the following command in your terminal

```
python3 -c 'import os; print(f"{int.from_bytes(os.urandom(1)):08b}")'
```

Here you get `8` coin flips at once.

#### Python file

For a bit more flexibility you can also save the following code as the file `coinflips.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys

def flip_coins_n_times(n:int):
    nbytes = n//8 + bool(n%8)
    # get random bytes, convert to bits (including leading zeros)
    # finally remove excess and print
    print(f"{int.from_bytes(os.urandom(nbytes), 'big'):0{8*nbytes}b}"[0:n]) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # file is run from commandline
    flip_coins_n_times(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

and run it from the command line as

```
$ python3 coinflips.py 20
11100100011100100111
$
```

Here you can replace `20` by the number of coinflips you want

Answer (score 0):

*[Adapted from WeatherVane's answer, but sufficiently different to write up separately]*

**Use one or more decks of cards for a precise 50% outcome**

- Define a set of rules so that given two cards one always "beats" the other (this could be a simple ordering or paper-scissors-rock-style non-transitive ordering to guarantee at least some suspense if the cards are revealed one at a time)
- Shuffle the cards and lay face down.
- Turn the top two cards (maybe one at a time to create more suspense!), and note whether first card beats second (outcome 1) or second beats first (outcome 2).
- Note that each outcome has exactly 50% probability, and this is easily observed / proved.
- Put BOTH cards in a discard pile.
- Keep taking pairs of cards for further 50% chances.
- Reshuffle when the cards run out.

Unlike the one-card solution, probabilities remain 50% until the end of the deck - someone counting cards will know what the last two cards are, and thus the outcome after only the first card is revealed, but not what order they're in.

For extra fun and/or aesthetic pleasure:

- rather than regular playing cards, use appropriately-themed cards with rules that make sense for the cards' theme about what beats what. There could even be multiple ways to compare the cards, with the player choosing which before revealing the cards (e.g. "highest strength stat wins").
- where outcomes are to be in favour of one player or another, split into two randomised decks instead of one, and each player draws from "their" deck to see who wins.

Comment: While I agree this produces a 50% chance, I'm unconvinced this is actually going to be less hassle than flipping a bunch of coins, particularly as you're going to have to explain it to your opponents before every game.

Answer (score -1):

This one.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Eduk8-Worldwide-Dice-Dome-Large/dp/B0751L83WS

odds=Heads
even=Tails

Comment: Link only answers are a bit problematic.  Consider adding some context to your answer so that folks don't need to click through to understand your answer.  Thanks!  [FAQ - How To Answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)